# Rewriting simple directory looping C sharp code in vbscript?

Tags: c#, vbscript, jscript, directoryinfo

I need to rewrite the following C sharp code in a language that does not require .NET due to such a wide spread of windows versions and .NET installations in our environment. I was thinking maybe VBScript, but I don't know how easily this would port over?

```
        try
        {
            string docsDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Mydocuments);

            if (Directory.Exists(docsDir))
            {
                // get all folders
                DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(docsDir);
                DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dInfo.GetDirectories();

                // start process
                Process p = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                info.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                info.UseShellExecute = false;

                p.StartInfo = info;
                p.Start();

                using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
                {
                    if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                    {
                        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine("FixPerms.exe" + dir.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a thought: can you maybe downgrade it to .NET 2.0 or even lower (to leverage fact, that usually machines with newer .NET can still run old code)? Or do you have some machines that don't have .NET at all?

Comment: What is your question? How easy is it to port over? This looks very simple...you can do it in batch/.cmd pretty easily.

Comment: @Gerino Unfortunately some machines do not have it installed at all, while others are running Windows 8 so will only (by default) run .NET 4.5 code.

Comment: @RufusL I'm trying to hide the process from view as it may take some time to complete and I dont want a cmd window open while it runs. I thought one of the native windows scripts might be best in this case, but I do not know whether you can use them to 'stream' commands to cmd.exe like in my code above.

Comment: you mean like (in a .bat file): `start /min cmd.exe ...`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a simple vbscript solution, this might help

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFolder(server.mappath(path))
Set sf = f.SubFolders 
for each fo in sf
```

Do Something

```
next
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick using a `.cmd` (or `.bat`) file, and should work on any windows system:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:: Set exit code to a failure code
SET /A EXITCODE=-1

:: Get the MyDocuments Folder
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=3" %%A IN ('REG.exe query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Personal"') DO (
    CALL :SetDocuments %%A
)

:: If MyDocuments doesn't exist, exit
IF NOT EXIST "%MyDocuments%" GOTO :END

:: Run the FixPerms.exe tool on each directory
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('DIR /B /AD "%MyDocuments%"') DO (
    CALL :RunProgramOnDirectory %%A
)

:: Set exit code to success
SET /A EXITCODE=0

:END
ENDLOCAL&EXIT /B %EXITCODE%

:SetDocuments
SET MyDocuments=%*
GOTO :EOF

:RunProgramOnDirectory
SET directoryName=%*
START /MIN CMD.exe /C FixPerms.exe "%directoryName%"
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Anyone know how I set the coloring for my code sample for .bat/.cmd?